# Trying to Delete Row on Dropdown Selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple block of code here that deletes a row if the selection equals "declined". I keep getting a runtime error 13 Type mismatch even though the row deletes. I'm not sure why I would be getting this error if the code executes what I want it to do. I just want to avoid an on error then next because I am going to build off of this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.Value = "Declined" Then
        Target.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're causing the event to re-fire by *changing* the sheet while deleting it. So turn events off with `Application.EnableEvents`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub ' << bail early if more than one cell was changed

    If Target.Value = "Declined" Then
        On Error GoTo SafeExit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

In your current setup, when the event re-fires after you initially do the delete, `Target` is now a reference to an *entire row*. Comparing an entire row to `"Declined"` is an automatic type mismatch: you're considering the row's `.Value`, which is a 2D array and cannot be compared to the string `"Declined"`.

Comment: Thank you! This works great. What is the reason for the Application.Enable Events?

Comment: It causes the event to *not* fire when you delete the row.